# Manage a pool of daemons threads

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon, watchservice

I have to handle a group of daemons that each implement a watchservice.
What I want to be able to do is, create the daemons, activate them, deactivate and remove.

At the moment at creation I do this to activate:

```
        private void activateDaemon(Daemon daemon){
            Thread thread = new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                            daemon.processEvents();
                    }
            };
            thread.start();
    }
```

Now this works, but if I want to deactivate and remove them. Deactivate stops the processevents (same method as in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html ) and should deallocte the thread. Remove should just destroy the daemon.

I'm thinking of using a Thread pool but am unsure of the implementation and the type. I don't want a fixed thread pool since I don't know the amount of desired daemons.    A Cached thread pool seem sufficient but the documentation tells me that it is only suitable for " applications that launch many short-lived tasks", while a daemon might run long.

How would I best go about safely managing, activating and deactiving a group of daemons (watchservices)?

Comment: Do you really need daemons or can you rephrase your problem using independent tasks (generated from the processed events) that are executed in a traditional Executor?

Comment: Daemon is just a naming convention. Daemon is a class that has a watchservice, nothing more nothing less. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Executor is just fine if that fits your task, the "short-lived" is just a hint but not required. The issue is that if you have a pool of lets say 10 threads and keep all 10 busy by waiting on a specific event, no other task can be processed in the meantime, because all 10 threads are busy.

There are two ways around this: first you can simply make sure that there are enough threads in the pool to process all tasks by creating a fixed-size thread pool, or second by working with a dispatcher model, where one scheduler awakes on every event, but then just dispatches the handling of that event to a thread in that pool, which is otherwise idle.

On the other hand you can use a ThreadGroup / ThreadFactory and create threads on your own, which is basically the fixed ThreadPoolExecutor but with more control and more work on your side.